# Start process with path space

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble with path spacing. This works:

```
$mediaPath = 'C:\Scripts'
$installerPath = Join-Path $mediaPath -ChildPath 'test.msi'

Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i $installerPath /quiet" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

This does not:

```
$mediaPath = 'C:\Scripts\Directory with a space\foo'
```

How to handle spaces in the path when passing arguments to `Start-Process`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the arguments improperly.

```
$media = 'C:\Scripts\test.msi'

Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList @('/i',"`"$media`"",'/quiet') -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the requirement for backticks ` and quotes ? `"` I'm new to PowerShell.

Comment: @LightningWar Those are escape characters so that it passes the argument as a quoted string, allowing spaces in the argument.  If you try to pass all your arguments as one string, it interprets that entire string as one argument and it's up to the program you're calling to interpret it, hence the string array I'm passing it in this example.  Note: escape characters are not interpreted in string literals (`''`).